# How can I show div onlick in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I want to display divreg template when someone click this button. My problem is that  I dont know how to write in in this method.

```
const divreg = {
      name: "divreg",
      template: `
<div>
 Hello

</div>  `
};

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    divreg
  },
  data: {
    message: "Załóż konto!"
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick() {
     //here I need to code to show this template onlick
    }
  },
  template: `
  <div>
  <h1> {{message}} </h1>
<divreg />
  <button @click="handleClick"> Zarejestruj się</button>
  </div>

  `
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `v-if` to show or hide the `element`, in your case it will something like this:

```
<divreg v-if="showElement" />
<button @click="handleClick"> Zarejestruj się</button>

data: () => ({
   showElement: false
})

methods: {
   handleClick() {
       this.showElement = true
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked thanks, but is there any idea to use something like this.divreg in my method to show it ? Just asking for future purposes

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <divreg v-if="showElement" />
  <button @click="showElement !== showElement">Zarejestruj się</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    showElement: false
  }),
}
</script>
```